# What is the difference between these 2 code pieces in Scala

Tags: scala, traits, difference

I want to understand the difference between these 2 codes.

Lets look at the following 2 pieces of code in Scala.

```
  trait Expressions {
    // Bunch of functions
  }
```

CODE 1:

```
trait Scheduling{
      val IR : Expressions
      import IR._
      // Bunch of functions
   }
```

CODE 2:

```
  trait Scheduling extends Expressions { 
    // Same Bunch of functions
  }
```

What is the difference between those 2 codes?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your first code snippet requires that any class that extends the trait has a variable named `IR` of type `Expressions`. All members of that variable are then imported so they can be used within your "bunch of functions".
The `Expression` instance is **aggregated**.

In your second example you're **inheriting** the trait. This requires that the class that implements your trait must also implement the `Expressions` trait.

Both example result in the same semantic: A implementation of all members of the `Expressions` trait is available to your "Bunch of methods".
The only difference is that aggregation is bit more flexible since you can use any object that implements the `Expressions`.

Your second example can be seen as equivalent to the first one if your trait implementation defines`val IR = this`.

Comment: They are not equivalent if you set `IR = this`, there are a number of other differences between the two approaches.

Comment: If `IR` is set to `this`, then a class that implements `Scheduling` must also implement`Expressions`. Thus the `import IR._` is like a `import this._`. Isn't that pretty much identitcal?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the key differences between the two versions of `Scheduling`:

Objects that inherit from `Scheduling` in CODE1...

- Must provide a `val IR` of type `Expressions`
- Have an extra member `IR` that is visible from outside the object
- May use a sub-class of `Expressions` with different implementations of the methods in `Expressions`
- Can access all the methods of `Expressions` as `IR.<method>`

Objects that inherit from `Scheduling` in CODE2..

- Have the type `Expressions`
- Can access all the methods of `Expressions` directly